# Laravel Multi-Tenancy Login using Central DB user OR Domain DB user

Tags: php, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I've Multi-Tenancy

1. Central DB has a user table
2. Domain DB also has a user table

So, 1st point is working by default but I want to check the entered login details that exist in Domain DB. If the user exists in Domain DB then the user should redirect to the dashboard file.

For point 2 I'm able to validate the user but while redirecting to the dashboard it redirects back to the login page.

Guys, can you guide me on this?